# Как вместо операции перенаправления stdin в цикле использовать конвейерную обработку?

Tags: bash

Прошу помочь решить задачу:

> Следующую часть кода предполагается использовать в сценарии,
> который отслеживает изменения в системном журнале /var/log/messages.
> К сожалению, этот код "зависает" и не делает ничего полезного. Почему?
> Найдите ошибку и исправьте ее (подсказка: вместо операции перенаправления
> stdin в цикл, попробуйте использовать конвейерную обработку).

```
while read LINE
do
 echo $LINE
done < `tail -f /var/log/messages`
```

Comment: `while read LINE; do  echo $LINE; done < <(tail -f /var/log/messages)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если отслеживание необходимо в режиме реального времени и нужно использовать конвейер, тогда

```bash
tail -f /var/log/messages | while read LINE; do
#Ну просто накрутим каких нибудь действий, так как просто echo ничего логического не несет, 
#потому что вывод просто команды и цикла будут идентичны
#Попробуем выделить строки содержащие err красным цветом '\033[31m'
    [[ "$LINE" =~ [Ee][Rr][Rr] ]] && color='\033[31m' || color='\033[1m'
#Выводим строку, \033[0m отключает цветовое выделение, что бы не перекрасить консоль
    echo -e "${color}${LINE}\033[0m"
done
```

В примере выше переменные не будут переданы за пределы цикла, т.е. если мы вызовем `echo "$color"` после `done`, то у нас вернется пустота.

---

Теперь попробуем иначе

```bash
while read LINE; do
#оставим аналогичные действия из примера выше.
    [[ "$LINE" =~ [Ee][Rr][Rr] ]] && color='\033[31m' || color='\033[1m'
#Выводим строку, \033[0m отключает цветовое выделение, что бы не перекрасить консоль
    echo -e "${color}${LINE}\033[0m"
done < <(tail -f /var/log/messages)
```

В данном случае переменные объявленные в цикле будут доступны за его пределами, так как передача данных в цикл идет не через пайп/конвейер.

---

Дополнение по поводу `tail`:
параметра `-f` - идентифицирует файл по дескриптору, т.е. если, к примеру, произошла ротация лога messeges.log, то программа перестанет выводить данные, продолжая следить за файлом который переименовали/переместили.
Для того, что бы смотреть за последней версией файла, нужно использовать параметр `-F` -который указывает программе читать файл по имени. Т.е. если в процессе отслеживания старый файл будет перенесен, а на его месте появится новый, то программа будет читать новый файл.

Answer (score 1):

`tail -f`
"Мониторит" файл на обновление и не закрывает его

`while read LINE`
Ждет бесконечно, закрытия файла, что бы прочесть построчно

`echo $LINE`
Никогда не вызывется

Исправленная версия

```
while read -r LINE
do
    echo "$LINE"
done < /var/log/messages
```

Если речь о bash работает и такая форма

```
< /var/log/messages | while read -r LINE
do
    echo "$LINE"
done
```

Comment: Вторая форма к конкретно bash не имеет отношения. Насколько я помню, это регулируется POSIX.